# Reading password from xml file in Oracle

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have XML file in which all the connections are stored. I have already imported all the connections into SQL Developer. Now I have to give password of a particular schema to other people. How can I decrypt the password of a particular schema?

Comment: That depends. How were those passwords encrypted?

Comment: Shouldn't your DBA be generating a password that can be given to the people that require it? Vs 'hacking' a protected file with passwords in it - which is encrypted to prevent the very thing you're trying to do.

Comment: You are right...but I have to share the password of dev enviornment ..so it is allowed if I can decrypt.